# Tkinter ScrolledText Widget scrolls really slowly

Tags: python, tkinter

Scrolling is super slow even for 67 kb of text that I'm loading using `os`. How can I make the scrolling smoother? Here is how I'm setting the text in the `ScrolledText` widget:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ScrolledText as tkst
import os

master = tk.Tk()

read_only = tkst.ScrolledText(master, width=20, height=10, wrap='word')
read_only.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")
read_only.pack()

text = open(directory + '/' + file).read()
read_only.delete('1.0', tk.END)
read_only.insert(tk.INSERT, text)
```

I also tried using a regular `Text` widget with a `Scrollbar` but I have the same issue:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

read_only = tk.Text(root, width=20, height=10, wrap='word', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
read_only.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")

text = open(directory + '/' + file, "r").read()
read_only.delete('1.0', tk.END)
read_only.insert(tk.INSERT, text)

read_only.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=read_only.yview)

mainloop()
```

Comment: why aren't you using the `scrollbar`-module from tkinter? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scrollbar.htm

Comment: Will that have better performance? Why doesn't the scrolled text widget scroll smoothly?

Comment: I haven't used `ScrolledText` yet. I have just some experience with `tkinter.Scrollbar` yet and I hadn't any problems with it yet

Comment: I tried using the `scrollbar` with a regular `Text` widget and I have the same problem. It's only a 67 kb file, so I wouldn't think it would be too much.

Comment: could you pls update your code?

Comment: you have to change `read_only` to:
`read_only = tk.Text(root, width=20, height=10, wrap='word', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)` Edit: Does it work?

Comment: That doesn't fix it. The text I'm trying to scroll through has 12,000 words in it, so it's a good amount of text but not an unreasonable amount. Is this just a limitation of Tkinter?

Comment: @TornaxO7: manually using a scrollbar won't offer any performance advantages over `ScrolledText` - `ScrolledText` uses the exact code you would use by creating your own scrollbar.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley oooh! Ok, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on `Tkinter` and went with `wxPython` instead. Here's an implementation of a scrollable text window using `wx`, which scrolls smoothly even with a lot of text:

```
import wx

text = 'Your Text Here'

class ScrollableTextWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.textpanel = wx.TextCtrl(parent, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.textpanel.SetValue(text)


app = wx.App(0)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY)
fa = ScrollableTextWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks to Teck's Treehouse for the answer: http://teck78.blogspot.com/2017/04/a-simple-solution-to-scrolling-text.html